# why does the hatchign stop after some time?

Tags: netlogo

Morning everybody

After editing my model, by adding a random spawn rate:

```
to migrate
  if random-float 100 < random-spawn-rate
  [create-turtles 2 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]]
end
```

i get the problem that after one kind of turtles (the boats) die out, even their random hatching seems to die out?
i tried other ways, but nothing really works

Please help me
thank you

Full code:

```
breed [fish a-fish]
breed [boats boat]
boats-own [profit]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor blue]

  set-default-shape fish "fish"
  create-fish initial-number-fish
  [
    set color grey
    set size 1.0
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  set-default-shape boats "boat"
  create-boats initial-number-boats
  [
    set color black
    set size 1.5
    set profit random (1 * profit-per-fish)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? turtles [stop]
  ask fish
   [
    move
    fish-reproduce
   ]
   ask boats
   [
     move-boats
     catch-fish
     death
     reproduce-boats
     migrate
   ]
   tick
end

to move
  rt random 50
  lt random 50
  fd 1
end


to fish-reproduce
  if random-float 100 < fish-growth
  [hatch 1 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]]
end

to move-boats
   rt random 50
  lt random 50
  fd 1
  set profit profit - 0.1
end

to catch-fish
  let prey one-of fish-here
  if prey != nobody
  [ask prey [die]
    set profit profit + profit-per-fish]
end

to death
  if profit < 0 [die]
end

to reproduce-boats
  if profit > 1
  [
    set profit (profit / 2)
    hatch 1 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]]
end


to migrate
  if random-float 100 < random-spawn-rate
  [create-turtles 2 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]]
end
```

Comment: did you still have fish when the boat creation stopped?

Comment: yes there are still fish, but the boat popullation dies out

Comment: i got it working thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no boats to hatch new boats, then no more boats will be created. Your hatch is dependent on how many boats there are.

Essentially, for a boat:

```
if profit > 1
  [
    set profit (profit / 2)
    hatch-boat 1 ...
   ]
```

You cut the profit in half for every boat spawned. Unless your profit grows or remains the same, your boats will eventually die out since no more will be hatching.